# Minimum Rights for SQL 2008r2 Backup/Restore User

Tags: sql, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to give our technician rights to restore one particular database from a backup file.  What are the minimum rights I can give him?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Server Role **dbcreator** to restore the database and the Database Role **db_backupoperator** to backup the database, as pointed out by @RBarryYoung in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10367060/702048) great answer.

You can specify these settings in the properties of the login, selecting the tab `Server Roles` and `User Mapping`.