# What are the user's (SQL) roles needed to take SQL Server database backup using SMO Backup class?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, smo

What are the user's (SQL) roles needed to take a SQL Server database backup using the SMO `Backup` class in C# as shown below? Does it use Windows authentication?

```
 Server myServer = new Server(servername);

 Backup bkp = new Backup();
 bkp.Action = BackupActionType.Database;

 Database myDatabase = myServer.Databases[database];

 bkp.Database = myDatabase.Name;
 bkp.Devices.AddDevice(path, DeviceType.File);
 bkp.BackupSetName = string.Format("{0} database Backup", database);
 bkp.BackupSetDescription=string.Format("{0} database - Full Backup", database);
 bkp.Initialize = true;

 bkp.SqlBackup(myServer);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to run `BACKUP DATABASE` and `BACKUP LOG` user must be members of the `sysadmin` fixed server role and the `db_owner` and `db_backupoperator` fixed database roles. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to take backup without having db_owner and sysadmin roles by using sql script or any c# code?

Comment: No, backups is a delicate thing, anybody could not have access to that kind of stuff. The backups are usually run by `sa`.

Comment: yes it not delicate thing.But there is a separate role called "db_backupoperator"

Comment: yes, it grants access to the database to make a backup, but not grant any rights to the server's file structure, which are needed to make the backup file. one of the workaround are mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366676/backup-permissions

Comment: I'v read this post. But does not a user need a sysadmin role  to create a new user?

Comment: As I remember user with sysasmin role can create new users.